# unable to install matplotlib under pythonw3.3 on mac

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib

I am trying to install matplotlib using this command:

```
pip install matplotlib
```

I get this error:

```
src/ft2font.h:16:10: fatal error: 'ft2build.h' file not found

#include <ft2build.h>

         ^

1 warning and 2 errors generated.

error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1
```

What does this error mean? I am able to install other packages like bumpy etc.

I did a

```
brew install freetype
```

I get this error:

```
Warning: freetype-2.5.2 already installed, it's just not linked
```

what does this mean?

I have the free type install as shown here:

```
/usr/local/include/freetype -> /usr/X11/include/freetype2/freetype
```

I am stuck, any ideas, any body?

Answer (score 0):

I follow the step on this site and it worked:

```
http://matplotlib.org/faq/installing_faq.html
```